# What can be a reason of jumping purple stripes on MSI laptop display?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, windows-11, laptop-repair, laptop-display

A few days ago just suddenly there appeared purple stripes on display. They are visible once laptop is turned on, including bios menu, and get much worse when changing refresh rate from 240hz to 60hz. After restart they reflect artefacts from the previously opened windows.
I tried updating the nvidia drivers/disabling discrete graphics/disabling integrated graphics - but nothing helped, unfortunately for me it's a hardware issue.
I'm just wondering what could cause this? Is there a chance it's not too difficult to repair?

[image]

Here's a video of how it looks
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16B22jr5eULPTqkkwiUsrbdH7CiYWpH2J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It can be the screen, the cable, or the video card(or motherboard). The problem is troubleshooting this. Without replacement parts to test with I’m not sure of any way to do that. Typically bad connections, screens and cables can be identified by disassembly and then flexing the screen connections, cables, motherboard / video card, etc. while the power is on can all help identify where the problem is. Because ultimately this is likely bad connection somewhere - whether it be a broken wire, cold solder joint, etc.

Comment: @Appleoddity, thank you for your response 

Comment: Has the laptop recently been dropped or experienced a sudden stop in momentum? Remember, it's not the fall that kills you, it the sudden stop at the end.